# Get all rows after the last occurrence of a specific value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

My dataframe looks like

```
ID  colA  
1      B     
1      D     
2      B    
2      D     
2      C
```

I have return all rows after the last occurrence of event B in each group. The output will be :

```
ID  colA   
1      D   
2      D     
2      C
```

I tried

```
a = df['colA'].str.contains('B').groupby(df['ID'])
b = df[(a.transform('sum') - a.cumsum()).eq(0)]
```

and it's working fine so far. I am just wondering if there is any alternative approach to achieve this?

Comment: Does this have to work for _each ID_?

Comment: If a group never contains `B` should it return nothing for that ID?

Comment: yes.It should return Nothing. But i have already filtered the dataframe to make sure it does have event B

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reverse your rows (this is important). Then call `groupby` and `cumsum`, and take all rows with (reversed) cumsum value equal to zero.

```
df[df.colA.eq('B')[::-1].astype(int).groupby(df.ID).cumsum().eq(0)]

   ID colA
1   1    D
3   2    D
4   2    C
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
ix = (df.colA.eq('B')
        .cumsum()
        .groupby(df.ID)
        .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.idxmax()+1:]).index.get_level_values(1))

df.loc[ix,:]

    ID colA
1   1    D
3   2    D
4   2    C
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
def yourlast(x):
        return x.loc[x.colA.where(df.colA.eq('B')).last_valid_index()+1:]
df.groupby('ID').apply(yourlast)
Out[163]: 
      ID colA
ID           
1  1   1    D
2  3   2    D
   4   2    C
```

Comment: You could probably add `group_keys=False` to get rid of the multiIndex. +1