# Filter certain rows in data frame based on time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge set of data and a dummy is shown here

[image]

Here, events is like a cycle . It can start with any event , stop at any event , but always ends with event-final. I get the sequence based on time. What I want to do here is keep only incomplete cycle records . For example , In above shown image , event-1 to event-final (first 4 rows) indicate that the cycle was complete , hence i need to remove all rows that are present before 'final-event' and I need only rows containing events after 'final-event' (in above pic case its event-2).

There are about 20 events that can occur in any order for a particular ID . So what i want to do is just delete off all the rows before final-event . I have time column to get the sequence.

My idea is to sort in descending order based on time and delete off rows after 'final-event'. But i am not sure how to do it in pandas. Can someone help in this?

Also is there a better approach to this other than my idea with the given data?

Edited to post the group by code (for @Joe Ferndz):

```
def remove_cycle(group):
    group = group.reset_index(drop=True)
    if not group[group['Event']=='event_final'].empty:
        tmp = group[group['Event']=='event_final']['time'].iloc[0]
        return group[group['time']>tmp]
    else:
        index = len(group)
    return group[:index]


temp2 = df.sort_values("time",ascending=False).groupby(["ID"]).apply(remove_cycle)
```

So, this is what I tried. I sorted in descending order based on time and then groupby on ID . Then in the remove_cycle I find out the index of the time for which the event is 'event-final'. Then I return back only rows having greater time column value.

This serves the purpose but it is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated Version: For Multiple IDs

This solution is inspired by the responses from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696046/get-all-rows-after-the-last-occurrence-of-a-specific-value-in-pandas)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['001']*10 + ['002']*10,
                   'Event':['event-1','event-2','event-3','event-final','event-1',
                            'event-2','event-3','event-final','event-1','event-2',
                            'event-1','event-2','event-3','event-final','event-1',
                            'event-2','event-final','event-1','event-2','event-3'],
                   'time':pd.date_range('2021-03-22 09:00:00', periods=20, freq="T")
                })

#converting time to string format to match your data
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime("%H:%M")

#checking for values of 'event-final' and reversing the dataframe to find groupby cumsum
#A value of 0 indicates that its after 'event-final'
#Picking those values will give you the desired results

print (df[df.Event.eq('event-final')[::-1].astype(int).groupby(df.ID).cumsum().eq(0)])

print (df)
```

The output will be:

```
     ID    Event   time
8   001  event-1  09:08
9   001  event-2  09:09
17  002  event-1  09:17
18  002  event-2  09:18
19  002  event-3  09:19
```

For a Dataframe:

```
     ID        Event   time
0   001      event-1  09:00
1   001      event-2  09:01
2   001      event-3  09:02
3   001  event-final  09:03
4   001      event-1  09:04
5   001      event-2  09:05
6   001      event-3  09:06
7   001  event-final  09:07
8   001      event-1  09:08
9   001      event-2  09:09
10  002      event-1  09:10
11  002      event-2  09:11
12  002      event-3  09:12
13  002  event-final  09:13
14  002      event-1  09:14
15  002      event-2  09:15
16  002  event-final  09:16
17  002      event-1  09:17
18  002      event-2  09:18
```

## Previous Answer for Single ID

You can find the index of the last occurrence of `event-final`, then list all the values from that point on. And yes, you need to sort_values by time and reset_index before you do this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['001']*10,
                   'Event':['event-1','event-2','event-3','event-final','event-1',
                            'event-2','event-3','event-final','event-1','event-2'],
                   'time':pd.date_range('2021-03-22 09:00:00', periods=10, freq="T")})

#converting time to string format to match your data

df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime("%H:%M")

#sorting time in ascending order (assume this is within same day
#if date goes beyond 24 hrs, then you should keep df['time'] in datetime format

df = df.sort_values(by='time').reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)

#find out the index of all events that have `event-final`
#and get only the last one using [-1]

idx = df.index[df['Event']=='event-final'][-1]

#using iloc or loc, you can get all records after the last `event-final` row
print (df.loc[idx+1:])
```

The output of this will be:

Original DataFrame:

```
    ID        Event   time
0  001      event-1  09:00
1  001      event-2  09:01
2  001      event-3  09:02
3  001  event-final  09:03
4  001      event-1  09:04
5  001      event-2  09:05
6  001      event-3  09:06
7  001  event-final  09:07
8  001      event-1  09:08
9  001      event-2  09:09
```

Final DataFrame without the event-final values.

```
    ID    Event   time
8  001  event-1  09:08
9  001  event-2  09:09
```

Comment: I have many ID's not only '001'. So in that case should I groupby first and then I have to use apply function and in that do as you said?

Comment: Ah!!! Yes, if you have many ids then we should groupby and pick the values. Let me create a dataframe with multiple ids and post an updated answer. Its very late in the night. I will post the answer tomorrow. Hope that's OK. Please try to explore using groupby. Use transform to flag the row that you need for cutoff. That way you can take all rows from that point onwards

Comment: Thanks a lot , I used group by with apply function to get the required result . It is time consuming tho..

Comment: With each group by set, you need to get only the last set of rows. Sorry abt not getting back to you earlier. Let me try to work on this and give you an update. In the meanwhile can you post your groupby code sp i can help you with speeding it up

Comment: I have edited the post and included the group by code. Let me know where i can improve on this. I tried not to exactly copy paste the same code you have written and gave a shot on my own based on your idea. Let me know what you think.

Comment: You can actually iterate through each groupby and pull the rows that you need

Comment: that is what I have done right? Or am I mistaken .. the argument 'group' takes in one group at a time is what I assume. Please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updated answer, It is much faster than my apply method